# javascript notify when script is loaded dynamically in IE

Tags: javascript

I have a small problem. I want to be notified when the script has finished loading. here is my code:

```
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
        var newScript = document.createElement('script');
        newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        newScript.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js';

        newScript.onreadystatechange= function () {
            if (script.readyState == "loaded" || script.readyState == "complete"){
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                alert("Script is ready!");
            }
        };
        newScript.onload= function(){
            alert("Script is ready 2!");

        };
```

Everything works ok in firefox, chrome, opera but not in Internet Explorer(IE9).
I found on this site that script.onreadystatechange is used by IE but it seems that is not working on IE9(I didn't tried on older versions). The script is loaded in IE but I don't receive the notification, which is important for me.

Thanks.

PS: I know there are similar questions on stackoverflow and I read them , but none of them solved my problem , or treat it in this particular way, that's why I created this one.

Comment: Have you tired jQuery? and if it works I wonder why it uses to get the ready state?

Comment: Have you set your HTML document to standards mode by including a fully qualified DOCTYPE? Check the rendering mode IE considers "default" for your page (can be found in the developer tools).

Comment: where are you getting/delcaring the variable script here??

Comment: @Amir Raminfar : The idea is that I'm trying to load jQuery

Comment: @Doua ha this is ironic!

Answer (score -1):

This is not particularly elegant solution but you can do an infinite loop and check if a variable in the loading script is set. If it is set then the script is loaded something like that:

```
    While(true){
         if( typeof foo != "unidentified" ){alert('loaded'); break;}
    }
```

Comment: using the While true can make your browser very slow