# document.attachEvent() not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am aware that in Internet Explorer (Pre-IE9) you cannot use `document.addEventListener()`, instead you must use `document.attachEvent`. The problem I'm having is that `document.attachEvent('onload', AddExternals);` does nothing, at all. In the console, the output should be as follows:

`- document.attachEvent
 - Adding Externals...
 - jQuery loaded!`

However in IE8, the console output is:

[image: ie8output]

Is there any obvious reason why this would occur in the below code?

```
if (document.addEventListener) {                    
    console.log("document.addEventListener")
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", AddExternals);
} else if (document.attachEvent) {                  
    console.log("document.attachEvent")
    document.attachEvent("onload", AddExternals);
}

function AddExternals(){
    console.log("Adding Externals...");
    var jq = document.createElement("script");
    jq.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jq);   
    jq.onload = function(){console.log("jQuery loaded!")};
    jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js";

}
```

**Edit**

I have changed `document.attachEvent("onload", AddExternals)` and now the console is outputting both `document.attachEvent` and `Adding Externals...` but the function never completes?

Comment: maybe because that event never gets triggered on the document? ...

Comment: Older versions of IE have no equivalent of DOMContentLoaded.

Comment: @KevinB So is there a work around for this?

Comment: window load. it will trigger much later than DOMContentLoaded, but it's  your only option other than moving all code to the end of the page, thus removing the need for the event all together.

Comment: You should be binding onload to the window, not document.

Comment: Okay I've got a step further. I now have both `document.attachEvent` and `Adding Externals...` in the console, but the function never completes?

Comment: Possible dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65434/getting-notified-when-the-page-dom-has-loaded-but-before-window-onload

Comment: @MikeResoli - see the possible explanation in my answer.  Old versions of IE do not have `.onload` for a script tag so it may be working, but you don't see the console message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no `document.onload` event.  Instead, you would use `window.onload` as your fallback.  You may also have to test the document state to make sure that it is not already loaded (e.g. the events have already fired).

For a completely tested function to know when the document is ready in any level of browser see the code in this prior question/answer: [pure JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's $.ready() how to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the/9899701#9899701)

Keep in mind that older versions of IE do not have a `.onload` for your script tag so you will not necessarily see that console message, but your script should still load.  There is a more complicated scheme that will get you notified of when it is loaded for older versions of IE here: [javascript notify when script is loaded dynamically in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204520/javascript-notify-when-script-is-loaded-dynamically-in-ie)

I would suggest you change your script to this:

```
function AddExternals(){

    var doneLoad = false;
    function onload() {
        if (!doneLoad) {
            doneLoad = true;
            console.log("jQuery loaded!")
        }
    }

    console.log("Adding Externals...");
    var jq = document.createElement("script");
    jq.type = "text/javascript";
    jq.onload = doneLoad;
    jq.onreadystatechange= function () {
        if (script.readyState == "loaded" || script.readyState == "complete"){
            doneLoad();
        }
    };
    jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jq);   

}
```

Relevant changes:

1. Added support for older method of knowing when the script has loaded.
2. Made sure there is no duplicate load notification since listening for multiple mechanisms
3. Set `.src` before inserting the script tag.